# Как запустить код заново. Я много чего пробовал но ничего не получается .Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python

```
gg = input("Что делаем? (+,-,*,/) :")

a = float( input("Первое число :" ) )
b = float( input("Второе число :" ) )

if gg == "+":
    c = a + b 
    
    import time 
    time.sleep(2)
    
    
    print( "Результат " + str(c))
    
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    
elif gg == "-":
    c = a - b 
    
    import time 
    time.sleep(2)
    
    print( "Результат " + str(c))
    
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    
elif gg == "*":
    c = a * b 
    
    import time 
    time.sleep(2)
    
    print( "Результат " + str(c))
    
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    
elif gg == "/":
    c = a / b 
    
    import time 
    time.sleep(2)
    
    print( "Результат " + str(c))
    
    import time
    time.sleep(1) 

reset = input ("Запустить калькулятор заново (да,нет) " )

if reset == "да":
  #Нужна помощь Срочно

elif reset == "нет":
  SystemExit(2)
```

Comment: Вкратце - положить код в цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    gg = input("Что делаем? (+,-,*,/) :")

    a = float( input("Первое число :" ) )
    b = float( input("Второе число :" ) )


    if gg == "+":
        c = a + b 
        
        import time 
        time.sleep(2)
        
        
        print( "Результат " + str(c))
        
        import time
        time.sleep(1)
        
    elif gg == "-":
        c = a - b 
        
        import time 
        time.sleep(2)
        
        print( "Результат " + str(c))
        
        import time
        time.sleep(1)
        
    elif gg == "*":
        c = a * b 
        
        import time 
        time.sleep(2)
        
        print( "Результат " + str(c))
        
        import time
        time.sleep(1)
        
    elif gg == "/":
        c = a / b 
        
        import time 
        time.sleep(2)
        
        print( "Результат " + str(c))
        
        import time
        time.sleep(1) 
    
    reset = input ("Запустить калькулятор заново (да,нет) " )
    
    if reset == "да":
        continue 
    
    elif reset == "нет":
      break
```

как вариант

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Но лучше не смотреть хауди и ему подобных :) а читать книги а доки :---)

Comment: Почему же, кончено возможно я не прав, но человек попросил, я сделал, вы удалили блок кода с задержкой и в целом изменили код (в лучшею сторону). Но ведь он просил не этого, хотя однозначнно ваш ответ лучше :)

Comment: дело в import time достаточно одного в начале кода.

Comment: @Arthur, во-первых, самая жесть - это уйма одинаковых импортов. Я не питонщик, но вообще сомневаюсь, что два одинаковых импорта могут находиться в одной области видимости. Дальше, во всех блоках одинаковый код по задержке и выводу результата - его логично разместить в одном месте. Если хочется пропускать вывод при неверном вводе, можно флаг завести - и то лучше будет, чем столько копипаста.

Comment: Пардон, для не питонщика не плохо :)

Comment: Разумеется, код вопроса ужасен, но видно, что человек пишет первый код после hello word'а и хоть и это и не причина писать плохо, ну всё же.

Comment: Можно и от ифов с мат операторами избавится путём ```ops = { '+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub } ``` хотя такая практика не есть гуд.

Comment: Так я ответом показывю к чему стоит стремится и мой код не идеален. Я сам на питоне пол годика, сюда звглядываю попрактиковаться, посмотреть интереснные решения

Comment: Правильно делайте,а я лентей полинился "переделать" код :) ну на самом деле это мой первый ответ на стак оверфлоу. Нужно тоже подтягивотся мне.

Comment: Простите но этот код мой первый и я особо не знаю особенности пайтона но я сделал как мог. Arthur спасибо точ то помог . Да ты прав это первый код после Hello world и я стараюсь учится . Может мой не идеален но пытаюсь создавать коды получше этого

Comment: user491812 по больше практики и все у вас получится  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
   gg = input("Что делаем? (+,-,*,/) :")
   a = float( input("Первое число :" ) )
   b = float( input("Второе число :" ) )

   if gg == "+":
      c = a + b
   elif gg == "-":
      c = a - b
   elif gg == "*":
      c = a * b
   elif gg == "/":
      c = a / b
   print( "Результат", c)

   reset = input ("Запустить калькулятор заново (да,нет) " )
   if reset == "нет":
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

Весь ваш калькулятор в 2 строчки

```py
while sentence := input('Введите выражение: '):
    print(eval(sentence))
# для того чтобы прервать выполнение просто нажмите Enter в пустом поле
```

> Конечно использование `eval` не то чтобы прямо очень хорошая практика, но и такие калькуляторы - зло в чистом виде заставляющее писать на С в Python